# How can I get jenkins/Jfrog to pull from my own artifactory AND another remote one?

Tags: maven, jenkins, dependencies, artifactory

I currently have artifactory set up on my jenkins pipeline correctly. I can see that it does indeed fetches artifacts but I noticed there is a few artifacts that arent being pulled. These artifacts dont seem to be in my jfrog server but i do specify in the POM file where they can be found and pulled. Here they are:

```
        <repository>
            <id>osgeo</id>
            <name>OSGeo Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
            <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>osgeo-snapshot</id>
            <name>OSGeo Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/snapshot/</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
            <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
        </repository>
```

I guess maven/jenkins only checks my artifactory server and doesnt reach out to these repos at all. Is there a way where I can tell maven to not just look in my artifactory repo and also look in these repos as well? I have this snippet of code in my main pom file so im clueless as to why it doesnt pull from them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424338/maven-settings-for-multiple-repositories. - Try this

Answer (score 0):

Artifactory does reach out these remote endpoints if they are configured. Check if these "https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/snapshot" and "https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release" are configured in the [remote repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF6X/Configuring+Repositories#ConfiguringRepositories-RemoteRepositories) and if not, create the maven remote repositories in Artifactory and point the URL textbox to these remote endpoints. Add these 2 remote repositories in the Maven [virtual repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF6X/Configuring+Repositories#ConfiguringRepositories-VirtualRepositories) and try to pull from Artifactory.

Comment: I prefer this option (creating a virtual repository in Artifactory) because in can work as a cache for external files. This way you can minimize time going to internet for downloading files. In your pom.xml you will need to add this repo in the repositories list.